# grep false positives

Tags: unix, grep

I have six html tags I care about checking if the self closing tag is incorrectly done. The tags are: `<input/><br/><hr/><img/><link/><meta/>`. I'm also looking for it to not have a space before the end tag because the page is xhtml. Basically I want to find ones that DON'T have self closing or if it does there is a space in front of it.

Right now I'm just focusing on one of the tags (input). It picks up some but not all. For instance, it picks up `<input type='submit' value='Save'>` which it is supposed to do. But it doesn't pick up `<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>`. It also picks up correct self closing tags like `<input type='submit' value='Save' /></td></tr>`

My grep is:

`grep "<input(.*[^/])>." *`

Any ideas why?

Comment: What about `grep -E "<input.*/?>" file.html`?.

Comment: @htor - that would give me all self closing tags. I want to find ones that DON'T have self closing or if it does there is a space in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Why should it pick up `<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>`? That's a correctly closed tag.

Comment: Forgot to mention in the post and I have corrected it above...I'm also looking for for the tags that don't have a space before the end tag to comply with xhtml.

Answer (score 0):

I think your current regexp isn't working because it's matching the entire line. Just eyeballing it, it looks like you're matching the opening string "`<input`" then as many characters as you can, with the final character being something other than a `/`, and then the closing `>`.

In the case of `<input type='submit' value='Save' /></td></tr>` since it's greedy, it'll run all the way to the last `>` that works. Which happens to be the `>` for the `td` (since your grep finishes with a `.`)

As a bit of a hack-y replacement (I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this..):

```
grep -P -o "<input.*?(?<=( .)|([^/]))>" test.html
```

(grep 2.6.3/cygwin if that's of relevance)

which roughly translates: get me anything starting with "`<input`", then ending with "`>`" (lazily), then look back and check that either that the 2nd last character before the closing `>` isn't a space, or that the last character isn't a close slash.

if test.html has (for argument's sake):

```
<input type='submit' value='Save' /></td></tr>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
<input type='submit' value='Save'>
<a><input type="blah" /></a>
<input/>
<input></i>
```

the output is:

```
<input type='submit' value='Save' />
<input type='submit' value='Save'>
<input type="blah" />
<input>
```

More generally though, if you're looking to test for compliance with xhtml, would [lxml](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) make your life easier?

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML using Regexes is [not advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

However if your HTML is formatted so that there's only one tag on each line, maybe you can get away with `grep '<input' * | grep -v " />"`